# Update of the code of conduct should contain a diff of the changes

Tags: feature-request, code-of-conduct

It makes it easier to understand the change when you are not a lawyer.

Comment: When asked for precisely this, staff's claim was, essentially, that they changed *all of it*, so a diff would be meaningless. It would show everything as deleted, and all new stuff added. Unfortunately, it seems, you have to break down and read the entire thing.